# WhenAny by property name

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm new to ReaciveUI and I'm performing some mock test to try and see its features and establish a framework around it to automate certain things. Right now I've reached a point where I want to observe a property but I only know its name. For example.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
{
      public ViewModelBase()
      {
          ObservePropertiesWithMyAttribute();
      }

      private void ObservePropertiesWithMyAttribute()
      {
            foreach(var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null))
            {
                //Observe the property
            }
      }
}
```

Is there any WhenAny overload that allows that? I've come with a happy idea (which obviously fails):

```
foreach(var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null))
 {
     Expression<Func<string>> expression = () => prop.Name;
     this.WhenAnyDynamic(expression.Body, x => x.Value).Subscribe(x => Text3 = $"Text is {x}");
 }
```

But it throws a System.NotSupportedException: "Unsupported expression type: Constant"

I know I can achieve the result I want through the PropertyChanged method, but I was curious if there's any chance of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an expression to access the property by string. Once you have that expression, you can pass it into `WhenAny`. Here's an example:

```
class X : ReactiveObject
{
    public X()
    {
        var propertyName = "A";
        this.WhenAny(GetProperty<int>(propertyName), c => c.GetValue() * c.GetValue())
            .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

    }
    int _a;
    public int A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _a, value); }
    }

    private Expression<Func<X, T>> GetProperty<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(X));
        Expression<Func<X, T>> expr = (Expression<Func<X, T>>)Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Property(param, propertyName),
            param
        );
        return expr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that, I actually need to know the actual class type (in this case, X). I can't implement that on a base class (e.g. ViewModelBase), unless I transform GetProperty<T> into GetProperty<T, X> and invoke it via Reflection MakeGenericMethod, but wouldn't that affect the performance significantly?

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile time, you're going to end up using reflection (or dynamic) one way or the other.

Comment: More generally though, part of the whole advantage of ReactiveUI is compile time checking. If you're at this level of contortion, you probably should just use PropertyChanged.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I din't have a solid reason to justify one or another decision. For me that's the real reason to use PropertyChange instead of other automation.